# How to share a scanned document from the Notes app with a shortcut

Tags: ios, pdf, sharing, notes.app, shortcuts-app

I have scanned PDFs I want to share to a shortcut to process them further. However, when sharing from the share sheet that props up when I click on the share button in the Notes app for my shortcut it does not receive the file.

This can be verified when scanning anything in a notes, opening it and pressing on the share button in the top right. Simply share it with a Shortcut that [displays the content graph](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/the-content-graph-engine-apd4618db957/5.0/ios/15.0).

Sharing a PDF from Files works as expected, but from the Notes app the graph is simply empty.

**Addendum:** It is possible to first save the files to the Files app, however this is impractical as the scanned PDFs are usually simply called `Scanned Document.pdf` which causes name collisions as well as not being practical to scroll through.

Comment: This is certainly a bug, I've filed it as FB9858508 myself but it seems to be that there's something wrong this this flow.